# When entering the correct data, an authorization error is generated

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-security

There is a `Spring MVC` project. There are 3 classes `Customer`, `Admin` and `Cook`. They all work through links to the main `User` class. Accordingly, there are User tables, from which the rest work through the *@OneToOne* connection. I added `Spring Security` to the project. Also added `html` - authorization. When logging in, it gives me an error that I entered the data incorrectly, although everything is correct I enter from the database.

What's my mistake. What am I doing wrong?

User:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

@ApiModel
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    public User() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }


    // Поля
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Size(min = 5, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;


    // Методы
    //
    // GrantedAuthority
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
    }


    // userName == login (одно и тоже)
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login;
    }


    // Во всех флагах стоит TRUE, так как не используются
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
    //
}
```

User:

```java
public enum Role {

    COOK, ADMIN, CUSTOMER

}
```

[image]

HOME:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>

<p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a greeting.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Login:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out.
</div>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

MvcConfig:

```java
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Поля
    //
    private UserService userService;


    // Injects in SETTERS
    //
    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }



    // Methods
    //
    // Тут мы переопределяем метод конфигураций
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }



    // Тут мы переопределяем для работы с внешней БД
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    // Тут мы используем encoder для шифрования паролей
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    // Возвращаем сервис пользовател для userDetServ
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userService;
    }
}
```

Comment: The passwords in DB are not bcrypt-encoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing passwords as plain text in DB and authentication is happening passwordEncoder comparison.

```java
auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
```

Store `password` as BCryptPasswordEncoded when you are storing user in DB.

```java
user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
```

OR
Compare plain text password (not recommended)

```java
auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
```

Comment: Code where you are creating users and saving in database.

Comment: Updated answer for alternative approach